# What is the definition of "feature" in neural network?

Tags: neural-network

I am a beginner of the neural network. I am very confused about the word `feature`. Can you give me a defintion of `feature`? Are the features the neurons in the hidden layers?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The features are the elements of your input vectors. The number of features is equal to the number of nodes in the input layer of the network.

If you were using a neural network to classify animals as either cats or dogs based on measurements of physical attributes, the features would be things like weight, tail length, ear size, etc. Each of these would have an initial value in kilograms, meters, and so on, and would then be normalized and centered at zero (within-feature) prior to presentation to the system.

So this cat:

> weight: 4kg 
> tail length: 0.3m 
> ear size: 2.5cm

Would be initially represented by the vector `[4, 0.2, 2]` and then after preprocessing (there would have to be other items in the dataset...) by something like `[-0.2, 0.3, .05]`

The features of an image of a letter could be as simple as the greyscale values of pixels. Other features could be generated by processing the images and extracting parameters from power spectra, or finding edges, etc. To learn more about this, seek out information about image processing and feature extraction.

Comment: So the number of features in this represented vector would be: 3 (?)

Comment: @naisanza yep. In the example above, there are three features that are used to represent each exemplar (person): height, weight, and hair length.

Comment: note: switched to a more appropriate classification task (cats vs. dogs) but the comment above seems understandable without modification

Answer (score 5):

Features in a neural network are the variables or attributes in your data set. You usually pick a subset of variables that can be used as good predictors by your model. So in a neural network, the features would be the input layer, not the hidden layer nodes. The output is whatever variable (or variables) you're trying to predict.

Comment: Thanks @Bill the Lizard and @ohruunuruus for the answers, but I still can not understand what means feature learning in `handwriting recognition`? What is the features of a letter? Some times they say, they need to ´learn feature´. What means that? Is it something like the corners of a letter?

Comment: @xirururu For handwriting recognition, you typically scan images of handwriting to train your model. If you have thousands of letters scanned at 10 x 10 pixel resolution, then all 100 pixels of those images would be your featues. The letter A will have different pixels darkened than the letter E. Once you train your model, it will be able to tell different letters apart based on those features. [Feature selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) is probably what's meant by "learn features."