# What is considered a feature in an Image in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I sort of understand what features are, say a ML algorithm that learns SPAM, certain keywords could be a feature?

But in the famous MNIST digits data set, I see a matrix of numbers, is the entire matrix one single feature? Or is a feature each number in the matrix?

Comment: Usually those are pixels and you feed all those pixels into your algorithm (often flattened 2d -> 1d; losing some information). So yes, every entry is a feature.

Comment: So each pixels light-darkness from 0-1 is a feature?

Comment: Yes. (bla bla to reach min-length of comment)

Comment: Then is correct to say I can select a feature(MNIST) to be: Stroke length, curvature, number of edges and extract that in use that as a feature to calculate the probability?

Comment: Those sound like new features introduced by processing the original ones. But sure, all those are features (multiple ones!).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you are lacking some critical literature review.
Here are some good papers about RNN and CNN that can be used for image recognition appications :

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/86ef/e7769f2b8a0e15ca213ab09881e6705caeb0.pdf
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.00019.pdf

What is a feature? A feature represents one of the elements of the input vector which will be used to train the model and produce output.

The feature set is to be determined depending on the application. 
Each element of the input vector is a different (dependent or independent) feature.

Look at this tutorial for example using the MNIST digit data set:
https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.py

It says:
'''
To classify images using a recurrent neural network, we consider every image
row as a sequence of pixels. Because MNIST image shape is 28*28px, we will then
handle 28 sequences of 28 steps for every sample.
'''

The RNN is built on sequences, hence if the image is 28 by 28 you can break it in 28 sequences of 28 features.

```
# Network Parameters
num_input = 28 # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
timesteps = 28 # timesteps
```

This is what you see in the network parameters. The 28 **features** (num_input = 28) representing one sequence of the image.

To repeat again, each element of the input vector is considered a feature. Furthermore, is the analyst's responsibility to properly define these features.

Comment: So the other guy in the first comment says each pixel is a feature probably because each pixel's location and intensity in combination can form a algorithm that shows probability of a certain digit. Is that a correct interpretation?   As for RNN, each feature was engineered to be a 28x1 vector, is this 2nd interpretation also correct?

Comment: Your input vector is made of features. Let's say you have a flower with attributes age, colour, name. Then {age, color, name} belonging to a flower is a feature set. You are lacking understanding of this basic principles. Each pixel is a feature because each pixel is one element of the input vector. If at the end of the input vector you add intensity, that's another feature.

Comment: The algorithm that shows the probability of a certain digit is determined by creating a mapping input vector -> output vector. That is x -> y. You offer a training set of n images of digit 1 with the output vector pointing to 1. Then the model learns the similarities of the input vector which points to the output vector.

Comment: You should go over basic Machine Learning stuff first. Like a training set, test set, validation set etc.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, a feature is a numerical value which discriminatively represents (or attempts to discriminatively represent) input or some part(s) of input. In case of MNIST, where image size is 28 x 28, the entire image matrix is flattened (generally row-wise) into a 1D feature vector, each element of this feature vector is a feature (in this case, simply image intensity). The type or kind of feature which one wants to use is completely problem specific. For e.g., instead of flattening the entire MNIST digit image, you could have used number of white pixels as your feature; however, it boils down to how discriminative such a feature could be for the given problem.

In case of spam classification, generally the features are frequency of words (there are several other things involved, such as stop word elimination, stemming, etc.).

One can off-course select or design multiple features for a given problem, such as stroke length, curvature, number of edges, etc. which you mentioned in the comment above. However, the main idea is that features should be discriminative enough for all the classes and they should not be derived from each other (this point leads us to another problem called feature or dimensionality reduction). I suggest you to read this Wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction) and then go on to read an academic presentation on feature extraction and dimensionality reduction, such as [this](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~urtasun/courses/CV/lecture04.pdf) (this one is specific to images). This would help you to understand the overall idea.

An additional note, the features are combined into a compact representation called a feature vector. In this particular case, as mentioned before, you have a 1-D feature vector, which contains image intensities as a features.

Comment: Sascha states that even 1 pixel is a feature, which to me makes some sense because the pixel has also a location and intensity(0..1), and in combination with other pixels, can be passed into a loss and cost function to get a correct classification, is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: Each element of the input vector is a feature. So yes 1 pixel is a feature if you break each pixel independently based on its position in the sequence. Hence if one image has 784 pixels and I have an input vector of length 784, I have 784 features. Otherwise if one image has 784 pixels, and I have only a 784 digits number so an input vector of length 1 that is 1 feature.

Comment: kunal18 is wrong in saying that the 1D vector represents a feature. That's completely wrong. The input vector is made of the feature set, where the length of the input vector gives the number of the features. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669854/what-is-the-definition-of-feature-in-neural-network

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake, really sorry about it. My intention was to actually refer to 1-D feature vector (not to be confused with feature, which are the elements of this vector) in this particular case of MNIST. However, again a feature vector need not be 1-D vector in general, it can be a n-D vector. I've made some corrections in the answer.